# Python: How to print without overwriting current typed input?

Tags: python

Is it possible to print something without overwriting the already written but not sent input?

This is the client side for a socket and I'm wanting to print messages from the server without overwriting/appending the currently written input.

```
def listen():
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))

def write():
    while True:
        text = input("Text > ")
        s.sendall(bytes(text, 'utf-8'))

listener = threading.Thread(target=listen)
listener.start()

writer = threading.Thread(target=write)
writer.start()
```

I'd want to print the received data above or below the current input line, but right now it just writes it on the input line.

Answer (score 1):

Interactive terminal input is complex and is usually handled with libraries, it's hard to handle it directly. For line input, `readline` and its alternatives such as `libedit` are popular. Most shells and REPLs use such libraries.

Python's standard library has `readline` module, which is interface to `readline` or `libedit`. Importing it makes `input` use `realine`/`libedit`, so it obtains cursor navigation and even auto-completion and history capabilities. And it allows to redraw input line after you draw something in terminal.

To print in previous line, you can use ANSI escape codes.

```
import threading
import sys
from time import sleep
import readline # importing readline makes input() use it

def listen():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        sleep(1)
        # <esc>[s - save cursor position
        # <esc>[1A - move cursor up
        # \r - carriage return
        # print message
        # <esc>[u - restore cursor position
        sys.stdout.write("\x1b[s\x1b[1A\rOutput: "+str(i)+"\x1b[u")
        readline.redisplay()

def write():
    while True:
        print "" # make space for printing messages
        text = input("Text > ")

listener = threading.Thread(target=listen)
listener.daemon = True
listener.start()

write()
```

`readline` library also has `rl_message` and other useful capabilities, but its' not exported by python's `readline` module.

Comment: (Not sure if my approach is *correct* way to do that and that it's 100% portable between terminals and versions of `readline`)

Answer (score 0):

Add `time.sleep(10)` after `s.sendall(bytes(text, 'utf-8'))`, because you immediately do input while the data is received and printed later. Having `time.sleep` you give time for the data to be received and printed.

But this won't help you if you enter the data for `input` too slow. Generally the code is strange, because why would you do `input` and `print` on the same terminal? In real life it doesn't make sense.

For academic purposes you can try this:

```
is_input_active = False

def listen():
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        while is_input_active:
            time.sleep(0.2)
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))

def write():
    global is_input_active
    while True:
        is_input_active = True
        text = input("Text > ")
        is_input_active = False
        s.sendall(bytes(text, 'utf-8'))
```

With this version `listen()` will block until `input` function finishes. If you don't want this, try something like:

```
def listen():
    data = b''
    while True:
        data += s.recv(1024)  # accumulate
        while not is_input_active:
            print(data.decode('utf-8'))
            data = b''  # reset
```